# python script to check disk space by passing argument

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, devops

I need help can someone please guide me how to write a script in python which will take a mount point as an argument and return a list of all the files on the mountpoint and their disk usage in bytes in json format

Example of output of script:-

```
getdiskusage.py /tmp
{
"files":
[
{"/tmp/foo", 1000},
{"/tmp/bar", 1000000},
{"/tmp/buzzz", 42},
],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- First list all the files in the given directory, including files in the subdirectory and store it in a list
- Run a for loop (list which includes all the files) and use getsize to get the size of the each file.
- Format the final output in the desired foramt.

```
def getListOfFiles(dirName):    
    try: 
        listOfFile = os.listdir(dirName)
        allFiles = list()        
        for entry in listOfFile:           
            fullPath = os.path.join(dirName, entry)
            if os.path.isdir(fullPath):
                allFiles = allFiles + getListOfFiles(fullPath)
            else:
                allFiles.append(fullPath)
        return allFiles
    except(FileNotFoundError):
        print("file not found")
        return 1

def main():    
    dirName = sys.argv[1]
    listOfFiles = getListOfFiles(dirName)
    listOfFiles = list()
    for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(dirName):
        listOfFiles += [os.path.join(dirpath, file) for file in filenames]

    print("{ \"files:\" [") 
    for elem in listOfFiles:
        print("{\"",elem,"\"", ",",os.path.getsize(elem),"},")
    print("],}") 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score -1):

Although you have not mentioned, what you have tried so far, you can start with the below code -

```
import os

direc = raw_input("Enter path: ")
files = os.listdir(direc)

for x in files:
  fullpath = direc + "/" + x
  if os.path.isfile(fullpath):
     hrfilesize = os.path.getsize(fullpath) / 1024
     print x,hrfilesize
```

There could be more optimizations and you will also need to account for getting this info in json format.

Comment: 1. Using command line arguments is not an "optimization". 2. You don't even try to handle files in subdirectories (and Python makes it very easy). 3. Please translate to Python 3. (Since this is not explicitly tagged "Python-2.7", assume the non-obsolete version.)

Comment: Like I said, this is not an optimum solution, but rather there is "scope" for optimization. It can be a starting point for OP.